# Fatal signal 11 when trying to use AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have been trying all day to solve this out, I am trying to call the following:

```
new DownloadandSaveAsync(Activity_picture.this).execute(image_url);
```

this is being called when clicking on an ImageView.

But as soon as my AsyncTask starts to load it just closes, with no crash report, just the following:

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 6744 (AsyncTask #4)
```

Here's my activity where I am calling it from:

```
public class Activity_picture extends ActionBarActivity {

public static final int ALBUM_RESULT = 300;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_picture);

    final String image_url = getIntent().getStringExtra("image_url");
    String image_title = getIntent().getStringExtra("image_title");

    ImageView picture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture);
    TextView pictureTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pictureTitle);

    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(image_url).into(picture);

    pictureTitle.setText(image_title);

    picture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new DownloadandSaveAsync(Activity_picture.this)
                    .execute(image_url);

            finish();

        }
    });

}
}
```

And then this is my AsyncTask code:

```
public class DownloadandSaveAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
Bitmap profPictBitmap;
Context context;

URL image_value;

public DownloadandSaveAsync(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {

        image_value = new URL(params[0]);

        System.out.println(image_value);

        profPictBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_value
                .openConnection().getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    File f = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "profileImage");
    try {
        f.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Convert bitmap to byte array
    Bitmap bitmap = profPictBitmap;

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /* ignored for PNG */, bos);
    byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

    // write the bytes in file
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        fos.write(bitmapdata);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, FeatherActivity.class);
    newIntent.setData(Uri.parse(f.toString()));
    newIntent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_IN_API_KEY_SECRET,
            "SECRET KEY");
    ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(newIntent, 1);

    if (pDialog != null) {
        if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

}

}
```

I am 100% sure the url that is being executed is not bad because I have done `System.out.println(image_value);` and it returns the correct URL as you will in the AsyncTask class.

I call this same AsyncTask code elsewhere in my app to download images and it works 100% fine when passing it other URLs, but for some weird reason I cannot understand, it force closes with that error.

If anyone would be able to help me out here, that would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you calling finish() in your onClick?

Comment: Because I want to finish that current activity after I've called my Async Task, I have also attempted to run the app without calling finish(); strait afterwards and that didn't do anything :(

Comment: Could you try to changing the `DownloadandSaveAsync` to extend `AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap>`, then in your `doInBackground` return the bitmap that you've decoded as opposed to using an instance variable to store the bitmap. I say this because I can't trust that `onPostExecute` is called synchronously.

Comment: Starting an AsyncTask and then immediately calling finish is smelly if not wrong-  what context owns the AsyncTask?  You're passing in a Context, that means your activity is going to be held onto and leaked.  If you need to have the task going on and the original activity finished it should be held by a Service.  By the time the download finishes your Context is no longer valid and that will cause all types of problems

You're also going to have problems in onPostExecute as you try to manipulate views and dialogs in a Context that no longer is valid.

Comment: @GabeSechan: it is downright wrong, especially since the AsyncTask is using the Activity to show a ProgressDialog.

Comment: OK, so I've attempted @idunnololz and have remove the "finish();" from the on click and it is still force closing.

Comment: yup. That finish() is killing things.  Although you start the async task first, you've just killed it's parent

Comment: @Martin I have completely removed that now, but am still getting the force close. I literally am ultimately stuck as to why it is behaving this way.

Comment: From your above code, it seems you are saving an image if i am not mistaken. What is the size of your bitmap image? Probably this error is due to your image size being too large.

Comment: if the image were too big, he'd be getting an Out-of-memory error.  A segmentation violation is when an address is outside the bounds of the program

Answer (score 0):

> In my case I am using Asynctask I got the same error

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

> I just add internet permission in the manifest file.After that it is worked to me